# Flurry analytics android how to set session level parameters

Tags: android, analytics, flurry, flurry-analytics

I want to set session level paramters in flurry

I want to know how can I use following two methods

addSessionProperty and setSessionOrigin

how and where it will be reflected in flurry dashboard.